# How to send JSON data from C++ DLL to Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

I want to send a dynamic size JSON data from the C++ DLL function to Delphi.
So wrote the following C++ DLL function

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) char* getJSON();
char* getJSON()
{       
    char jsonArrray[] = "{\"id\":\"1\",\"language\":\"español\"}";
    return jsonArrray;  
}
```

Here is the Delphi code:

```
function  getJSON: PChar; cdecl;  external "testCPP.dll";

var    
    pVal:  Pchar;
    A: array[0..100] of wideChar;
begin 
    pVal := A;
    pVal := getJSON;    
    Writeln(pVal);
end
```

Comment: I don't know C++ well enough to write exact code, but I know that you must use a global variable for the buffer (jsonArray), not a local variable, since it will go out of scope as soon as the function returns, so the memory pVal points to in the Delphi part is already invalid. Also, you might need to use wchar_t instead of char, or a one-byte character type on the Delphi side instead of WideChar, so that character types match. Also, you probably need to indicate the JSON length somehow, either by #0 terminating the array or returning a length.

Comment: As the code is now, the array A in Delphi is not really used. pVal is set to point to it first, but immediate after, pVal is set to point to the array in the C++ DLL instead (and A is no longer used for anything. The line pVal := getJSON does not copy the array, it just makes pVal point to the memory that the C++ jsonArray occupied (but which is already invalid). So the Delphi side will also have to copy the array, not just point to it.

Comment: No. Don't use a global. Either have the caller allocate the buffer. Or allocate on a shared heap.

Comment: In your code, Delphi `PChar` is likely to be a `PWideChar` (since Delphi 2009), whereas `char*` is an `AnsiChar` buffer. So it won't work for sure like that.

Anyway, get rid of memory allocation problems by using `WideString` / `BSTR` to allocate the data.